# Getting column 'threshold.threshold' is invalid in the having clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Getting column 'threshold.threshold' is invalid in the having clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause.
This is my code..

`SELECT ITEM.ITEMS, SUM(ITEM.REORGANIZED) AS TOTAL
FROM THRESHOLD CROSS JOIN ITEM
GROUP BY ITEM.ITEMS
HAVING (SUM(ITEM.REORGANIZED) > THRESHOLD.THRESHOLD)`

here,i have error in threshold.threshold...threshold is a single integer value..if i use 600 instead of threshold.threshold means it will work...

How to clear the error???

Comment: What do you mean by *threshold is a input value given by user*

Comment: threshold is a single integer value

Comment: If you mean that the `THRESHOLD` table contains a single row, then just add `THRESHOLD.THRESHOLD` in the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY` clause, as the error message is already hinting. If there are *multiple* rows, then things get more complicated - you need to articulate a rule (to us and/or to SQL Server) to describe *which* row's value to use in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

having (SUM(ITEM.REORGANIZED) > (select threshold from threshold)

it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try to aggregate `THRESHOLD.THRESHOLD` field using MIN or MAX function as below:

```
SELECT ITEM.ITEMS, SUM(ITEM.REORGANIZED) AS TOTAL
FROM THRESHOLD CROSS JOIN ITEM
GROUP BY ITEM.ITEMS
HAVING (SUM(ITEM.REORGANIZED) > MAX(THRESHOLD.THRESHOLD))
```

I hope this will help!!